# JavaScript event, when we select the input filed value from the browser cache

Tags: javascript

I have a input text field and a button to submit. I want the button to be enabled only when i enter something into text field. I used `onchange="enableButton();"` `onkeyup="this.onchange();"` `onpaste="this.onchange();"` `oninput="this.onchange();"`

but when i double click on input field a dropdown appears from cache and upon selecting the value from this dropdown no event fires.
Can anyone please suggest me how to do enable button.

Comment: That seems like a browser fault to me. Selecting an item from auto-completion should trigger `onchange`.

Comment: I am using IE8, but this code works fine with FireFox

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by deferring onchange actions via `setImmediate`, which allows other pending events to be processed first. In your case, try setting onchange to this: `onchange="setImmediate(enableButton)"`.